# Signal R username password validation through .net winform client & parallel connections

Tags: signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am planning to use SignalR 2 to implement notification feature in one of my project. I have created a self hosted server using Hub class. It provides OnConnected() and OnDisconnected virtual methods where I can implement custom client authentication using username/password. Client is developed in .net win forms. I want to know what the options available to achieve followings:

1) How can I send username/password to server? I tried sending through hub connection Headers, QueryString dictionaries. But username password are being transferred thorough wire in plain text. I want to send securely.

2) In server, is there any way to authenticate user before connection establishes completely? I mean, before OnConnected method gets called. I don't want connection to be opened completely until user is validated.

3) How many parallel connections can be opened on one self hosted Signal R server?

I need to call another WCF web service method to validate the connecting user.

I read security options documented [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/introduction-to-security) but don't see any option. I tried creating custom Authorize attribute inheriting Authorize class but all the methods are getting called multiple times if connection is successful. Here is the ref - [Authentication and Authorization for SignalR Hubs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/security/hub-authorization)

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this link might help some of your problems.
The sample is only about Authentication, and I have implemented the SignalR to also require authentication.

https://github.com/louislewis2/AngularJSAuthentication

Perhaps you can get an idea from the code and implement the rest for your needs.

Louis